# Sourcetable.Select providing 2 columns of data does not work

Tags: c#

I created a method that takes a source data table, destination data table, column name and value. The copies only data rows that  match the value of the column. This works but now I need to give 2 column names and 2 values but it is not working.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public void SortDataByType(DataTable SourceTable, DataTable ReturnedResult, String Custnum, string Columnname)
{
        var detailedRows = SourceTable.Select(String.Format(Columnname + "={0}", Custnum));

        foreach (var detailRow in detailedRows)
        {
            ReturnedResult.Rows.Add(detailRow.ItemArray);
        }
    }
```

Above works fine.

Below code does not work.

```
 public void SortDataByType(DataTable SourceTable, DataTable ReturnedResult, String Custnum,   String District , string Columnname,string Columnname2)
 {
     var detailedRows = SourceTable.Select(String.Format(Columnname + "={0}" , Columnname2+"={1}",Custnum,District));

     foreach (var detailRow in detailedRows)
     {
            ReturnedResult.Rows.Add(detailRow.ItemArray);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable.Select can combine conditions using "AND" or "OR" statements. Try this:

```
var detailedRows = SourceTable.Select(String.Format(Columnname + " = {0}" + " And " + Columnname2 + " = {1}", Custnum, District));
```